# ChannelInboundHandler.channelRead is getting invoked before connect's ChannelFutureListener.operationComplete

Tags: netty

I have a client server application written using netty and Ive noticed a race condition recently which is due to ChannelInboundHandler.channelRead getting invoked before connect's ChannelFutureListener.operationComplete.

My understanding was that when a client accepts a connection, the connect's channelFutureListener must be invoked first before processing the first message from the socket. I suppose the ordering is guaranteed by executing the connect's channelFutureListener on the same I/O thread assigned for the connection which is responsible for reading data from socket.

But Im not sure why Im not seeing this guaranteed ordering from netty but instead the two events are either executed concurrently or in the reverse order.

What is the best practice on using channelFutureListener, is there a way to use it such that it can be guaranteed to execute before the next event for the same socket is processed?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct... If this is the case its a bug... Please open an issue with all the details (reproducer would be awesome) in the netty bug-tracker.

Comment: Thanks Norman! After enabling netty debug logs, I think we understand the issue. The call to netty to connect is like: b.connect(<address>).addListener(...); It seems like the connection was established before the addListener could be completed. Is there an atomic way to request connection with a connect listener or set listener before connect request, so I can guarantee that connect listener will always be the first one to be called?

Comment: Yes there is... You can use `bootstrap.register()` and then use `channel.connect(....)` with a `ChannelPromise` as an argument. Here you can add the listener to the promise before you call connect.